# Character Case Problems

Tags: php, mysql, character

So I have my login form in my website.

And for example my username is JuvarAbrera (saved in mysql).

When I try to login using this username ---> juvarabrera

It is still logged-in in my website. Now, I want it NOT to logged-in because of the the J and A are uppercased.

So, how can I do that? I think I explained it very well.

Thanks. :)

Comment: How have you setup the login scripts? Have you written these yourself or used a pre-built or packaged login system?

Comment: @Nikson `UPPER` or `LOWER` are completely senseless in this case

Comment: @bendataclear I'm making my own login system. :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can collate the value in the query:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'php_value' COLLATE utf8_general_cs
```

Comment: using `COLLATE` is also a fine method, but `utf8_general_cs` would allow using a username like `JüvärÄbrerä` because it handles string based on language rules and I think that's not what the poster wants

Comment: That is a fair point, I just assumed he was only concerned with case sensitivity. Thanks for adding that into the mix though!

Comment: Hey @BenM, just checking if this is correct. --> SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' AND password = '$mypassword' COLLATE utf8_general_cs LIMIT 1

Comment: Yes, that should achieve case sensitive matches.

Comment: Whoa, careful! It's quite important to set the COLLATE value for the `username` column in the DBMS, especially if that column is supposed to have unique values (or is a primary key).  Else you're going to get strange behavior: false detection of duplicate keys.

Answer (score 4):

Change column collation to `utf8_bin` (i.e. when using `utf8_general_ci`)

Take care of `*_general_*` collations because comparisions base on language rules. So have a look

in `utf8_general_ci` the following is true: `'a'='A'`, `'ä'='A'`
in `utf8_general_cs` the following is true: `'Ä'='A'`
in `utf8_bin` none of these is true, and I think that's what you want

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL query will allow for upper-cased names:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   login 
WHERE  uname         = '$username' AND 
       BINARY(uname) = BINARY('$username')
```